# writing ogg player with gstreamer

Tags: c, video, video-streaming, gstreamer

i'm new to gstreamer and i want to write an ogg player from the scratch.
until now i could write the audio part, which plays audio from an ogg video file. 
**my specific question is how can i handle both video and audio from demuxer**. briefly i want implement below pipeline. but i dont know how can i split demuxer's audio and video sinks and connect them to appropriate decoders.[image]
The code which handles audio part is here(which exists on the internet):

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>


static gboolean
bus_call (GstBus     *bus,
          GstMessage *msg,
          gpointer    data)
{
  GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {

    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("End of stream\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      gchar  *debug;
      GError *error;

      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
      g_free (debug);

      g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);

      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}


static void
on_pad_added (GstElement *element,
              GstPad     *pad,
              gpointer    data)
{
  GstPad *sinkpad;
  GstElement *decoder = (GstElement *) data;

  /* We can now link this pad with the vorbis-decoder sink pad */
  g_print ("Dynamic pad created, linking demuxer/decoder\n");

  sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (decoder, "sink");

  gst_pad_link (pad, sinkpad);

  gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
}



int
main (int   argc,
      char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;

  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *demuxer, *decoder, *conv, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;
  guint bus_watch_id;

  /* Initialisation */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);


  /* Check input arguments */
  if (argc != 2) {
    g_printerr ("Usage: %s <Ogg/Vorbis filename>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }


  /* Create gstreamer elements */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("audio-player");
  source   = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc",       "file-source");
  demuxer  = gst_element_factory_make ("oggdemux",      "ogg-demuxer");
  decoder  = gst_element_factory_make ("vorbisdec",     "vorbis-decoder");
  conv     = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert",  "converter");
  sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !demuxer || !decoder || !conv || !sink) {
    g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Set up the pipeline */

  /* we set the input filename to the source element */
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", argv[1], NULL);

  /* we add a message handler */
  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
  bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  /* we add all elements into the pipeline */
  /* file-source | ogg-demuxer | vorbis-decoder | converter | alsa-output */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline),
                    source, demuxer, decoder, conv, sink, NULL);

  /* we link the elements together */
  /* file-source -> ogg-demuxer ~> vorbis-decoder -> converter -> alsa-output */
  gst_element_link (source, demuxer);
  gst_element_link_many (decoder, conv, sink, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), decoder);

  /* Set the pipeline to "playing" state*/
  g_print ("Now playing: %s\n", argv[1]);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);


  /* Iterate */
  g_print ("Running...\n");
  g_main_loop_run (loop);


  /* Out of the main loop, clean up nicely */
  g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  g_print ("Deleting pipeline\n");
  gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
  g_source_remove (bus_watch_id);
  g_main_loop_unref (loop);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a pipeline to run Vorbis and Theora decoders with a gst-launch:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.ogg ! oggdemux name=demuxer ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! theoradec ! autovideosink
```

To do it in C, just create more video elements and add all of them to the `pipeline` bin by adding them to `gst_bin_add_many()`. Then link them one to another with `gst_element_link()` or `gst_element_link_many()` according to the topology you want.